# JavaScript SDK events don't fire

Tags: javascript, facebook, events, sdk

I am using the JS SDK to tie into facebook.  After initialization (FB.init()), I see the Login button.  After clicking it, it prompts me to login.   Then the dialog just goes away after I log in, despite the fact that I am using FB.Event.subscribe() to add a handler to the auth.login event.

Note that I include the Facebook all.js file using a  tag in html which is processed prior to this code.

here is my code:

```
FB.init({

                            appId:myId,
                            channelUrl:myChannelUrl,
                            cookie:true,
                            status:true,
                            xfbml:true
                     });
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',function(response) {
                            alert("your event finally fired!!!");
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout',function(){
                    alert("you logged out");
            });
```

---

Now, when I log in or log out, NOTHING happens.  The facebook dialog simply goes away.  If I purposely use incorrect credentials to attempt log in, the dialog properly rejects the attempt, which proves that the thing is indeed communicating with facebook.  The trouble seems to be that the event is not firing.

thank you for any guidance here.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to this event instead.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);
```

and in your javascript,

```
function handleStatusChange(response) {
if(response.authResponse ==  'connected')
//do something
else
//do something else
}
```

Ref: http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hello/

Comment: thank you Dark.  But its still not working.   Is there a way to see some sort of error console in real time on Facebook's end?   So I can see what they see?

Comment: Most probably, this isn't a problem with facebook's end. See that example I gave under ref. That javascript works and it uses the `auth.statusChange` that I outlined.

Comment: This question is answered (I figured it out).  Stack, however, wont let me answer my own question( not enough reputation?).

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question and mark it as answer.

Comment: curious to know the answer, as in my case also no event is getting fired. tried all sorts of possible solutions.